# How to deploy windows service to onprem vm from azure devops server?

Tags: azure-devops, windows-services

Im new to devops , and im trying to deploy windows service to on premises vm,

I have added **Copy file from** task and setup all the user name/ password/ source/ destination and all the required settings.

but error

> [error]Failed to Create PSDrive with Destination:
>   '\my_server\D$\TestCI', ErrorMessage: 'The network path was not
>   found'

fails the release.

can you help on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you work on the Azure Devops Server，you should be using self-hosted agents.

> ErrorMessage: 'The network path was not found'

The casue of this issue could be that the `Self-hosted agent` and the `Target windows machine` are not in the same `Windows Domain`.

To solve this issue, you could try to create a new self-hosted agent under the **same windows domain** (the machine which in the **same local network**), then grant the permissions for the build agent service account to access another local PC.

Here is the ticket with [the similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57798063/13464420), you could refer to it.